# TeX4ht and \xymatrix{} diagram

Tags: tex4ht

TeX4ht is generating a png file from an `\xymatrix{}` environment in LaTeX, however this png file is not being attached to the resulting xml file like
LaTeX figures - just a blank area is left.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal working example?